# How to get a deferred handler to return a value to the calling function?

Tags: javascript, dojo, deferred

Look at the below example to understand what I am trying to do:

```
//Caller.js
callingFunction : function (...)
{
    var a = new Assistant();
    console.log("This object has been returned ", a.showDialog(...));
},

//Assistant.js
showDialog : function (...)
{
    deferred.then(lang.hitch(this, this._showDialog));
    //I want to return someObject to callingFunction
},

_showDialog : function (dialogData)
{
    ...
    ...
    return someObject;
},}
```

Comment: I'm really not the one here to give the right answer since I don't use  Dojo, but I just read in another question here that `promise`s are good for that in terms of it will execute a callback even if you add it after the event that should trigger it has already happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's deferred, there is nothing for it to return before that function ends. Instead, pass a callback into `showDialog` and have it call that callback when the deferred fires.

---

Re your comment below:

> Do you know how I would add a callback to that?

It's been *years* since I used Dojo, so it may have features to make this shorter, but the usual way would look like this:

```
showDialog : function (callback)
{
    deferred.then(lang.hitch(this, function() {
        this._showDialog();
        callback(/*...whatever it is you want to pass back...*/);
    }));
},
```

Comment: Do you know how I would add a callback to that?

Comment: @antonpug: Added an example

Comment: So whatever the callback returns is going to get returned as if it is returned from showDialog?

Comment: @antonpug: You pass a function into `showDialog`. `showDialog` will have no return value (it can't, if the source of that value is asynchronous). Later, when the deferred runs, the callback function you passed into `showDialog` will get called by the deferred, with whatever arguments you tell it to provide. If `this._showDialog` returns what you want to pass to the callback, then you'd change the anonymous function you're passing into `hitch` to `function() { callback(this._showDialog()); }`.

Comment: So if I have an external class calling thisClass.showDialog(), then how can I get showDialog to return a value to externalClass?