# How to return a value from a deferred?

Tags: javascript, dojo, callback, deferred

I am calling a method that has some logic in a deferred, and when that logic finishes, I want to return the value to the callee. See below:

```
//Callee.js
var myAssistant = new Assistant();
console.log(myAssistant.whatIsTheValue());



//Assistant.js
whatIsTheValue : function(someArg) {
   var deferred = someService.getSomething();
   deferred.then(lang.hitch(this, this._getTheValue));

   //In theory, I want to return whatever this._getTheValue returns, how can I do that?!
}

_getTheValue() {
   ...
   ...
   return xyz;
}
```

Comment: You seem not to have understood Deferreds.

Comment: I get the basic concept. I am just not seeing the workaround to this issue.

Comment: Also there is no reason to ask the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260686/how-to-get-a-deferred-handler-to-return-a-value-to-the-calling-function?rq=1
you'll notice that you got basically the same answers both times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what your `lang.hitch` does, but the solution should look like that:

```
Assistant.prototype.whatIsTheValue = function(someArg) {
    var deferred = someService.getSomething();
    return deferred.then(lang.hitch(this, this._getTheValue));
//  ^^^^^^
};

var myAssistant = new Assistant();
myAssistant.whatIsTheValue().then(console.log); // use console.log.bind(console) in Chrome
//                           ^^^^ - it is a promise you return
```

Answer (score 2):

Deferreds are asynchronous operations.  Therefore you can't return a variable in a normal way from them because they will not execute until after the current function context completes.

If you want to do more with that value you will need to do so in terms of another callback (IE chaining the then statements.)

The point of deferreds is to provide sequential operations for callbacks.  So you can chain them to achieve the results you want.  If you need the results to be available in your current execution context, you're going to have to find a synchronous (not deferreds) method of doing what you want.

So something like this

```
//Assistant.js
whatIsTheValue : function(someArg) {
   var deferred = someService.getSomething();
   var next = deferred.then(lang.hitch(this, this._getTheValue));
   next.then(/*insert next function here*/);
}
```

You need to understand that using a deferred lang.hitch isn't going to execute until after whatistheValue is done operating.  So instead of returning the value to whatever function called whatisthevalue, you're going to have to put the logic of processing that value into a new function and use that as an additional callback for your deferred.  This will probably require some restructuring of your program.

Comment: In effect, I want to return a value, once we have a value

Comment: you're going to have to use callbacks, and do whatever you want to do within the callback.  There's no way to immediately return a value into that function contecxt because you're making an asynchronous call and it won't execute until the event has occurred and your current function context has completed.

Answer (score 1):

use JQuery's `$when` instead.

Example

```
// assuming both getData and getLocation return their respective Promise
var combinedPromise = $.when(getData(), getLocation())

// function will be called when both getData and getLocation resolve
combinePromise.done(function(data,location){
  alert("We got data: " + dataResult + " and location: " + location);
});
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/